# cross domain less css

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, less, github-pages

I'm trying to load [LESS](http://lesscss.org) files across domains and am, of course, running into cross-domain issues.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load xxxxxxxxxxxxx. Origin yyyyyyyyyyy is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101: A network error occurred in synchronous requests.
```

Yes... I know... I should be compiling my LESS files to CSS before they reach the browser. But that's not an option. And I'm not so obsessive that the 0.02s compile time in the client really bothers me that much anyway.

To add to the problem I'd like to, at least in the short term, host said files using [github pages](http://pages.github.com). So have no real control over the hosting environment (as far as I know).

Is there any way I can a) get less.js to do safe cross-domain xhr requests, or b) teach github pages how to Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

A tall request, I know, but I thought I'd put it out there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a proxy to handle those requests?

http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html